# Android app and iPhone app connection with PHP website

Tags: php, android, ios

I am developing a `PHP` website and we want to launch mobile apps too. We are still learning. My friend, who has developed apps for `Android` and the `iPhone`, is experienced in app development but all his projects were like offline apps. He knows how to develop apps that can communicate with a server and fetch data from a server but I still want to help him. Can anyone tell me what we will need to make such an app? I know that we will need an `XML` script on the server to communicate with the `Android` app. But what we will need in the `XML` file to communicate with the app to fetch data from the database? I need a basic idea. Waiting for response. I use Stackoverflow to get some ideas. I always ask for ideas and basic code - not harder stuff - and I have always received great responses from you all. Thank you for helping me in advance. ;)

Comment: JSON http://www.json.org/

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials for consuming webservice with android! [This one, for example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) This question is quite vague as we don't know your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

here is a php script I made some time ago to retrieve data from my server to an app. You put it on the server side and have your ios or android app call it from the application to get the json.
Hope you find it useful!

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect(yourdatabaseaddressprobablylocalhost,yourusername,yourpassword);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db(yourdatabasename, $con);


$result = mysql_query(yourmysqlquery);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode((array('arrayname'=> $output))));

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanx. This will help a lot to. ;) Still waiting for more ideas. :D

Answer (score 0):

and Either cases, use HTTP POST and Get request to communicate with PHP server & Database